# How can I fix this package body creation error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I'm making a package to collect some functions in the same place. But while I attempt to create the body it always has an error.

I have tried everything I know, but it doesn´t matter how much do I try it always gives me the same error

This is my package which does not bring me any error.

```
create or replace PACKAGE talde_paquete AS
procedure editaldeak(Equipo Taldeak.Kod_taldea%TYPE, Nombre Taldeak.izena%TYPE, Localidad Taldeak.Herria%TYPE, Correo taldeak.helbide_elektronikoa%TYPE,Campo Taldeak.Zelaia%TYPE);
procedure equipopartidos(Equipo partidak.talde1%TYPE);
END talde_paquete;
```

And this is my package body which is the one who brings me always the same error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY talde_paquete 
IS
procedure editaldea(Equipo Taldeak.Kod_taldea%TYPE, Nombre Taldeak.izena%TYPE, Localidad Taldeak.Herria%TYPE, Correo taldeak.helbide_elektronikoa%TYPE,Campo Taldeak.Zelaia%TYPE)
AS
VTaldea NUMBER(1);
Taldenoexist EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(Kod_Taldea) INTO VTaldea FROM Taldeak WHERE Kod_Taldea=Equipo;
    IF VTaldea=1 THEN
        UPDATE Taldeak SET Izena=Nombre, Herria=Localidad, Helbide_Elektronikoa=Correo, Zelaia=Campo WHERE Kod_taldea=Equipo;
    ELSE
        RAISE Taldenoexist;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Taldenoexist THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Taldea ez da existitzen');
END editaldea;
procedure equipopartidos(Equipo partidak.talde1%TYPE)
IS
    CURSOR PartidoEquipo IS
        SELECT Talde1, Talde2, P_Data FROM Partidak WHERE Talde1 LIKE Equipo OR Talde2 LIKE Equipo;
    E1 Partidak.Talde1%TYPE;
    E2 Partidak.Talde2%TYPE;
    Fecha Partidak.P_Data%TYPE;
    existe NUMBER(3);
    Taldexist EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(Talde1) INTO existe FROM partidak WHERE Talde1=Equipo OR Talde2=Equipo;
    IF (existe>0)THEN
    OPEN PartidoEquipo;
    FETCH PartidoEquipo INTO E1,E2,Fecha;
    WHILE PartidoEquipo%FOUND LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(E1||' taldeak '||E2||' taldearen aurka jokatuko du '||Fecha);
        FETCH PartidoEquipo INTO E1,E2,Fecha;
    END LOOP;
        CLOSE PartidoEquipo;
    ELSE
    RAISE Taldexist;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Taldexist THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Taldea ez da existitzen');
END equipopartidos;
END talde_paquete;
/
```

And here is the error that I get when I'm attempting to run the body script.

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14      PLS-00905: object BIZKAIABASKET.TALDE_PAQUETE is invalid
1/14      PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'TALDE_PAQUETE' without its specification
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: its' simple, just read the error message and fix the problem. your package spec is invalid, so find out why

Comment: Maybe you are missing an / as the last line of your package specification . Without that the code will not be executed and the specification will be missing. Your package body does have that / at the end.

Comment: The error means that the spec exists but is invalid - so "This is my package wich does not bring me any error." can't be true. Run just the spec compilation again and see what it says; and/or query `user_errors` to see what that shows. (Presumably one of the table or column names is wrong, but we can't see your schema, so you will have to investigate...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hotfix is absolutely right, the error message when compiling is quite clear. The definition of the procedures in the body must be the same as the one defined in the header, I notice that there is a difference in the name `editaldeak` vs `editaldea`

Comment: That's true, and well spotted; but the body compilation isn't getting that far. If the spec was valid and the only problem was that discrepancy in the body definition, the body would get PLS-00323 and PLS-00328. The error the OP is actually getting means the spec itself is invalid - so it doesn't even try to compile the body. (I imagine the real problem is a similar typo in a table or column name in the spec, but we haven't been given the error that gets.)

Comment: That's right, the problem is typographical, it will suffice to fix the name of the procedures are the same, depends on our partner @benat-garrido-de-ordorika